# Kubernetes TLS all the way to the pod

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I just started using Istio and securing service to service communication and have two questions:

1. When using nginx ingress, will Istio secure the data from the ingress controller to the service with TLS?
2. Is it possible to secure with TLS all the way to the pod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. With "Envoy" deployed as sidecar container to both i.e. (a) **NGINX POD** and (b) **Application POD**, istio will ensure that both the services communicate to each-other over TLS.
2. Infact that's the whole idea behind using Istio i.e. to secure all the communication way till the POD using ENVOY side-car. Envoy will intercept all the traffic going in/out of the POD and perform TLS communication with the peer Envoy counterpart.

All this is done in a transparent manner i.e transparent to the application container. The responsibility to perform TLS layer jobs ex. handshake, encryption/decryption, peer discovery etc. are all offloaded to the envoy sidecar.

Comment: so if I have two Pods and Envoy as sidecar, there will be TLS used (if configured)?

Comment: yes. you need to ensure that both the Pods have got envoy as additional container.

Comment: thanks a lot, really helped in this confusing stuff :) thats what happens if secrity relies on third party... :D

Comment: But in a way it's helpful for the developer as all the overload of managing certificates and that too with a transient environment where pods come and go often is centrally managed. Also,  the application logic doesn't need to bother with the nitty gritties of the secure transport layer. I agree that said it may not be right to centralize all the security aspect on a 3rd party.

Comment: yes that is what I meant. But the fact that you do not have to worry about TLS in the application is nice. BTW what happens if you open (e.g. in Java) a HttpsUrlConnection with Istio?